# Sequence incremented randomly postgres

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

We have a primary key of serial type that is incremented automatically based on Postgres sequence.

The problem is this field at midnight start having a big gaps between it values. example:

```
    Id
189040207
189040238
189040239
189040251
189040264
189040265
```

We don't have delete operation on this tables (we do only soft delete).
We are using Postgres 9.3.

Comment: Gaps in a sequence are to be expected and are **not** a problem.

Comment: The sequence will be incremented regardless of the transaction success.

Comment: If gaps in sequences are a problem for your app, fix the app or use a different (and much slower) assignment method than sequences.

Comment: Yes I agree that sequence incrementing shouldn't be a problem itself, but the aborted transactions for example can be cause it. What we are doing now is investigating the number aborted transactions and errors in logs to find what changed suddenly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed above the real problem is not the sequence it self but we found that we had a big number of aborted transactions!

And after fixing the sequence issue was fixed as well.